# Running postflight script when installing a package on Mac

Tags: macos, installation, packagemaker, productbuild, pkgbuild

I am trying to build a mac package installer from a script and I want to run postinstall and postflight scripts. My script for building the package looks like this:

```
pkgbuild --root MyRoot/MyApp.app --identifier com.myapp.MyApp --scripts Scripts --install-location /Applications/MyApp.app MyApp.pkg
productbuild --synthesize --package MyApp.pkg Distribution.xml
productbuild --distribution Distribution.xml --resources Resources --package-path . CompleteInstaller.pkg
```

I've placed the postinstall script in Scripts and it is being executed successfully. I have a problem with running the postflight script though. It is placed in the Resources directory and doesn't get executed. Is this not enough to specify the path to it? I couldn't find an answer to this question, I'm sorry if I've missed it.

PS: My postflight script does nothing special - for now it tries to create a file in the home directory:

```
#!/bin/sh
touch ~/file
exit 0
```

Comment: How can this possibly work with the typo "Scirpts"?!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am not sure why do you have both `postinstall` and `postflight` in a package. Both are same scripts which must be run after the "copy files" phase of the installation.
"`postflight`" name was used in older style packages - bundles.
After the introduction of flat packages, the same script has to be named as "`postinstall`".
In flat packages, installer treats a file as a postinstall script only if its name is "postinstall", not "postflight" and is present inside "`Scripts`" directory, not "`Resources`" directory.
Probably, this is the reason your script is not being executed.

You can get some more information regarding scripts used in packages [here](https://macinstallers.blogspot.com/2012/07/scripting-in-installer-packages.html).

Comment: I have been trying with post_install like it used to be, for almost an hour :) Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Nice post @Vikram Singh

Comment: Extra tip: my scripts seemed to be correctly named but they were not working. Until I noticed they had the extension .command which was hidden by MacOS. Once I removed .command, all was well.